# Updating Redis Click-To-Deploy Configuration on Compute Engine

Tags: redis, google-compute-engine

I've deployed a single micro-instance redis on compute engine using the (very convenient) click-to-deploy feature.

I would now like to update this configuration to have a couple of instances, so that I can benchmark how this increases performance.

Is it possible to modify the config while it's running?

The other option would be to add a whole new redis deployment, bleed traffic onto that over time and eventually shut down the old one. Not only does this sound like a pain in the butt, but, I also can't see any way in the web UI to click-to-deploy multiple clusters.

I've got my learners license with all this, so would also appreciate any general 'good-to-knows'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the Google Cloud team working on this feature and wanted to chime in. Sorry no one replied to this for so long.

We are working on some of the features you describe that would surely make the service more useful and powerful. Stay tuned on that.

I admit that there really is not a good solution for modifying an existing deployment to date, unless you launch a new cluster and migrate your data over / redirect reads and writes to the new cluster.  This is a limitation we are working to fix.

As a workaround for creating two deployments using Click to Deploy with Redis, you could create a separate project.

Also, if you wanted to migrate to your own template using the Deployment Manager API https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/overview, keep in mind Deployment Manager does not have this limitation, and you can create multiple deployments from the same template in the same project.

Chris